# Idiomatic function composition in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

Is there an idiomatic way for defining a function via function composition in Common Lisp? I am currently setting the fdefinition of a symbol like this:

`(setf (fdefinition 'key-fn) (util:compose #'util:make-keyword #'str:upcase #'str:param-case))`

util in this case contains the Alexandria and Serapeum utility libraries.

Comment: For the setf, see `serapeum:defalias` (whose use is orthogonal to function composition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most idiomatic solution would be to write a little higher-order function that composes functions.

A simple implementation could be like:

```lisp
(defun compose (f g)
  #'(lambda (x) (funcall f (funcall g x))))
```

The `compose` function takes as arguments two functions (each which take only one argument) and returns a function that takes one argument.

```
CL-USER> (funcall (compose #'1+ #'1+) 0)
2
```

The above will work for many common use-cases, but a slightly more general version could be written that composes an arbitrary number of function arguments. Paul Graham writes something like this function in his book *ANSI Common Lisp* in Chapter 6.6 about higher-order functions:

```lisp
(defun compose-many (&rest fns)
  (destructuring-bind (inner-fn . outer-fns) (reverse fns)
    #'(lambda (&rest args)
        (reduce #'(lambda (val fn) (funcall fn val))
                outer-fns
                :initial-value (apply inner-fn args)))))
```

The `compose-many` function takes one or more function arguments to be composed. The inner-most function can take an arbitrary number of arguments itself, but all remaining functions must take only one argument. The function returned by `compose-many` takes an arbitrary number of arguments to be passed to the inner-most function.

```
CL-USER> (funcall (compose-many #'1+ #'1+ #'*) 2 3)
8
```

In the last example `#'*` can take any number of arguments, but `#'1+` takes exactly one argument.

### Is there an idiomatic / better way for the definition part?

Since symbols in Common Lisp have value cells and function cells there isn't a simple `def`-like form. The OP posted method of using `setf` with `fdefinition` is the way to accomplish this.

You could write a `defcompose` macro that makes this all more convenient:

```lisp
(defmacro defcompose (fname &rest args)
  `(progn (intern (string-upcase ',fname))
          (setf (fdefinition ',fname) (compose-many ,@args))))
```

This `defcompose` macro interns a symbol in the current package before binding a composed function to its function cell.

```
CL-USER> (defcompose my-composition #'1+ #'1+ #'*)
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (&REST ARGS) :IN COMPOSE-MANY) {1001D4698B}>
CL-USER> (my-composition 2 3)
8
```

### Adding Documentation Strings

Often you just want to compose functions for a one-off use, e.g., to pass a function argument to another function. In these cases there is no need to bind the function to a symbol in the global name space, and you can just use something like the `compose-many` function above.

If you *do* want to create globally available functions using composition you might also want to add documentation strings. This is simple to add, but here the functions to be composed are passed explicitly in a list to distinguish them from an optional documentation string:

```
(defmacro defcompose (fname args &optional docs)
  `(progn (intern (string-upcase ',fname))
          (setf (fdefinition ',fname) (compose-many ,@args))
          (setf (documentation #',fname 'function) ,docs)))
```

```
CL-USER> (defcompose my-composition (#'1+ #'1+ #'*)
           "Multiplies its arguments together and adds two to the result.")
"Multiplies its arguments together and adds two to the result."
CL-USER> (my-composition 3 2)
8
CL-USER> (documentation #'my-composition 'function)
"Multiplies its arguments together and adds two to the result."
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer but this is not what I meant. Is there an idiomatic / better way for the definition part  `setf (fdefinition 'key-fn)`? For example in clojure there is `def`as in `(def some-function (comp inc dec))`

Comment: @Kungi -- I have added to my answer addressing the definition part.

Comment: Thank you. So the "idiomatic" way would be to roll your own macro :-)

Comment: @Kungi -- _"to roll your own macro"_ -- probably not if you only need to create one or two symbol-bound composed functions. But if you need better syntax, that's what macros are for ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think alexandria:compose works well for this.

```
(let ((composite (compose '1+
                              (lambda (x)
                                (* x 2))
                              #'read-from-string)))
      (funcall composite "1"))
;; 3
```

There's a few variants in alexandria, and I know I've seen one or two libraries that extend these functions.